# Error while loading rule 'jsx-a11y/alt-text': rule.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint

I've just used
`npx create-react-app my-app`
to start one project and when running `npm start`
i'm receiving this compiling error

```
Error while loading rule 'jsx-a11y/alt-text': rule.create is not a function
Occurred while linting my-app/src/index.js
```

Comment: A new CRA app works OK for me (Node 16.13, macOS Monterey) and it looks like none of CRA, ESLint or the jsx-a11y plug-in have been updated recently. That said [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69910146/3001761) seems to be having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @jonrsharpe, when i checked that other issue i was gonna check and i don't know why and how, it worked doing absolutely nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably hit https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/824 where Version 6.5.0 was causing this issue while it was marked as latest on npm. A fix has now been released with version 6.5.1 and it solved  the issue for me.